# Can Autoincrement field ever use the same value twice?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table1 with an id field, type AutoIncrement. I need to copy the entire record from table1 into table2 if there is no record with the same id in table2. Then I delete the record from table1.

I need to know that if table1 gets new records, the id field will never be a number that was ever used before. Does this happen automatically, or do I need to do something to ensure this?

I tried deleting some records and adding new ones, and it really didn't use the same id, but I'm not sure that this is what always happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is really so, Auto-increment fields in MS Access are always incremental, even if records are deleted, database compacted, etc.
The proposed number can be reset deleting the auto-increment field, perform the copy of the table and then adding the auto-increment field again.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to duplicate numbers in autoincremet field quite easy, but normally applications don't work this way.

Access remembers last inserted value in autoincrement field and uses it for calculating next value. You cannot insert particular value into autoincrement field using table designer or recordset in VBA, but it's possible if you use `INSERT` SQL statement. So, if autoincrement field has no unique index, you can insert any value. Also if you insert value less than maximum existing number, Access will generate duplicates automatically.

So I would not recommend rely on unique autoincrement numbers without unique index.

`INSERT` SQL can be used for resetting numeration without dropping field/table, just run query like this in query builder or using VBA:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 ( id ) SELECT 1;
```

This is table with autoincrement field `ID` I just created:

[image]

Comment: If you delete it or if create table manually and reject adding primary key

Comment: @SergeyS. The above INSERT statement resets the auto-numbering, even if the field ID is defined as Unique Key. MS Access store the last inserted ID, in this case 1, and continues incrementally to add 1 when a new record is inserted. I did not mention that because this behavior can lead to errors if the table is not empty when the INSERT statement is executed, and no check is made when the new ID is calculated.
Deleting and recreating the ID will recalculate all IDs and the table be in a  'consistent' state. Having said that, what you wrote in your post is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 2):

Auto increment never uses the same # even though it's deleted from the table.

It requires complete reset so that it will start from the base and create new #.